# How to make an autorun folder

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, autorun, user-folders

I need to make something with a folder to have all relevant files in it and then run stuff.

I have some Excel sheets that need some helping files with it. I need to share it with others but (to avoid user problems) I want it all tied in a neatly pack for them to use...

I was thinking of "ziping" it in a folder with relative links and delivering what they would see as "one file", but everything would work.

Comment: You'll want a self-extracting executable and work with relative paths as much as possible to tie it all together. I know from experience that Winrar has a really good and high-customizable self-extracting module, allowing you to basically make an installer with shortcut support.

Comment: Keep in mind that .exe files are rarely allowed to be delivered via email. So you need to send these files a different way.

Comment: @Appleoddity - Agreed.  Even if allowed, users with even a modicum of cyber security understanding will certainly never open an emailed `.exe` file.